# Reference in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I change the code in jQuery which will be referred to the items above in the html?

Html code is as follows:

```
<div class="dramer">
    <ul>
        <li> </li>
        <li> <a class="shares" href="#"> Click </a> </li>
        <li> </li>
        <li> </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="drops"> </div>

</div>
```

The code in jQuery:

```
$('a.shares').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).next(."drops").slideToggle(400);    
});
```

Function in jQuery is designed to show and hide div located out of the reach `<li>` and `<ul>`

How can I modify the code to hide jQuery and show div?

Comment: Can you please clarify your problem? I don't understand what it is.

Comment: I could't really get it. Do you mean you want to hide the div on click of the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>`$ (this). next(. "drops"). slideToggle (400);`</s>

```
$(this).closest('.dramer').children('.drops').slideToggle(400);
```

Answer (score 2):

Target it directly

```
$(".drops").slideToggle(400);
```

If you need it to be context aware, something like this might work

```
$(this).closest(".dramer").find(".drops").slideToggle(400);
```

Comment: Need to remove the quotes around `this`, as well as the space that precedes `(` in the first and second.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying

```
$ ('a.shares'). click (function (event) {
         event.preventDefault ();
         event.stopPropagation ();
         $(this).parent(".dramer").children(".drops").slideToggle(400);
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should go up to the nearest ancestor that is shared between `.shares` and `.drops`, and then find `.drops` from there:

```
$(".shares").on("click", toggleDrops);

function toggleDrops (event) {
    $(this).closest(".dramer").find(".drops").slideToggle(400);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you what. If you mean you want to hide the div which is a child of your , you can try this:

```
$ ('a.shares'). click (function (event) {
    event.preventDefault ();
    event.stopPropagation ();
    $(".drops").slideToggle (400);
});
```